# How to get a single data from Firebase without using FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve a single data or field from the Firestore. Like `firstName`, `lastName` or `title` of **user1** in this case

[image]

I've gone through the [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs) documentation, it was using `FutureBuilder` to read data from Firestore. I searched about this on Stack Overflow also but didn't get any perfect answer for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question as I didn't find any perfect answer for this question.

```
//Initialising as 'loading..' because text widget (where you'll be using these variables) can't be null
String firstName = 'loading...'
String lastName = 'loading...'
String title = 'loading...'

class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {

  //Creating a reference to the collection 'users'
  CollectionReference collectionReference =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  //This function will set the values to firstName, lastName and title from the data fetched from firestore 
  void getUsersData() {
    collectionReferenceToOrderacWeb.doc('user1').get().then((value) {

      //'value' is the instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
      //'value.data()' contains all the data inside a document in the form of 'dictionary'
      var fields = value.data();

      //Using 'setState' to update the user's data inside the app
      //firstName, lastName and title are 'initialised variables'
      setState(() {
        firstName = fields['firstName'];
        lastName = fields['lastName'];
        title = fields['title'];
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just reframing the above solution a bit for those who didn't find exactly what they are looking for (get data of all the documents of a collection)**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Screen extends StatefulWidget{
  final String documentId;
  Screen({this.documentId});

  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}
class _ScreenState extends State<Screen>{
  String itemName = '';
  String itemImage = '';  //Initializing string bcz image requires a path
  String itemQuantity = '';
  CollectionReference collectionReference =
       FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CollectionName');
  @override
  void initState(){
    //documentId is passed from previous widget
    collectionReference.doc(widget.documentId).get().then((value) {
      //'value' is the instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
      //'value.data()' contains all the data inside a document in the form of 'dictionary'
      setState(() {
        //name, image, quantity are the fields of document
        itemName = value.data()['name']; 
        itemImage = value.data()['image'];
        itemQuantity = value.data()['quantity'].toString(); //quantity field is of type number in firebase
        //while retrieving numerical value from firebase, convert it to string before displaying
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Image.network(itemImage),
        Text(itemName),
        Text(itemQuantity),
      ]
    ));
  }
}
```